# How can I expand my guild?

Tags: spiral-knights

When I first started playing Spiral Knights, I met a really nice guy who invited me into his guild. We played often with an assortment of around 5 other guild members, and me and one other worked our way up to the rank of Guild Master.

Lately, our guild has come across rough times. The third Guild Master and our only other officer both quit, and any new recruits we manage to get quit immediately when they see that it's just me and the other Guild Master online. I haven't seen anyone else come on.

How can I revive my guild? How can I make it hit critical mass?

Answer (score 3):

Keep inviting. There's bound to be someone join. Also, try and advertise in Haven, using the /zone chat. Some apprentice will probably come along and like the idea of being in a guild and having the  shown under his name.

Comment: This usually works at least it's how i normally get a guild running with a few of my friends

Comment: I tried this for a long time.  New recruits would see how inactive the guild was, and quit the next day.  :\  I eventually did get about 2-3 loyal members, and then we merged into a far larger guild.